Swift closure context (unknown layout)
While running the Debug Memory Graph on Xcode for an Mac app I created, I noticed these nodes (unsure of the right term) which said Swift closure context (unknown layout).
I could not pinpoint the problem, so I created a new blank app and tried running the Debug Memory Graph again, getting the same nodes.

No changes have been made on the new app from the template generated by Xcode, so where are these coming from? Are you guys able to replicate this?
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


